# Redirect port / port 10000 to https apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have been reading around and trying different configurations to get a request to my server on port 10000 to redirect a http to a https request.

For some reason I can't figure out how to make it happen when i use port 10000 although i can set a rewrite rule for port 80 (implicit) to do it:

All I want is a request as follows:

```
http://example.com:10000
```

to redirect me to

```
https://example.com:10000
```

My current, vhost, the last of many different attempts is currently set as follows, but it doesn't seem to work at all:

```
<VirtualHost *:10000>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_POST}%{REQUEST_URI}

ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/webmin-redirect_error_log.log"
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/webmin-redirect_access_log.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I'v also tried a few other things but nothing seems to work, any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT: I already have a re-write in my httpd.conf that redirects port 80 to https.
If I access port 10000 externally it is redirected to https, but from the lan "http://192.168.0.2:10000" it doesnt.**

Comment: Are you trying to redirect requests to Webmin? If I remember correctly, webmin has it's own web server and doesn't use Apache. So inside the LAN, you might be hitting webmin's server and the request never gets to Apache.

Comment: Indeed I am trying to do it with webmin, that would make sense, I'll poke around, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide whether port 10000 is HTTP or HTTPS. For HTTPS you will have to create a virtualhost of it's own with SSL* configuration lines. You cannot have both in the same IP in the same port.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it in:

- Webmin > Config Webmin > SSl Config
- Check yes in > Redirect non-SSL requests to SSL mode?
- Reload browser and clear cache (Ctrl + Shift +R)

Answer (score -1):

This can be archived by redirecting to a custom "400 - Bad Request" page and modify the redirection with a rewrite rule. In the following example i request

> **http**://test.mydomain.com:**27000**

and get redirected to

> **https**://test.mydomain.com:**27000**

with one virtual host.

Code:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}:27000/$1 [R,L]
```

Or you simply redirect directly to the HTTPS version of the page.

Code:

```
 ErrorDocument 400 https://test.mydomain.com:27000
```

But you will loose the ability to redirect on a real "Bad Request" page.