# Apache answer both HTTP and HTTPS on the same port

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

I'm trying to get apache to redirect from http to https, however I want them both on the same port (20100, but I doubt that will matter). Basically what's going on [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/330381/redirect-port-port-10000-to-https-apache) except I'm not doing this for webmin. Currently I have it configured to serve HTTPS, and when I access with HTTP I get:

```
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
```

There seem to be a lot of somewhat similar questions, however I am unable to find one that actually answers my question.

Comment: For those who find this question through Google: Serving both HTTP and HTTPS on the same port is totally possible — see https://github.com/mscdex/httpolyglot . The highly-voted negative answers are just saying that it's just not necessarily solvable using _only_ Apache and no other tools at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is not going to be possible with Apache.  With Apache you cannot have HTTPS and HTTP running on the same port.

I am aware of a few port-multiplexers designed to make **HTTPS**/OpenVPN and **SSH** run on the same port, but these require additional software.

- SSLH: http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml
- Multiplex: http://www.pond-weed.com/multiplex/ (appears to be dead)

Comment: Damn. Oh well. Would it be possible to have apache simply redirect to the HTTPS version of the page from the HTTP version?

Comment: Sure.  do a quick search here there are many questions that cover that.

Comment: Yeah so I've discovered, however they all assume that you're running http on port 80 and https on port 443. None (that i could find) work for to redirect http requests to https on the same port.

Comment: @thefinn93 The same port still won't work in Apache, regardless of what you're trying to answer with - a full page or a redirect.  You need software in front of the listener that can make decisions on request routing based on the protocol the client sends - HAProxy may do the trick.  But why go through all this effort - why not just use a different port?

Comment: Alright. I assumed since apache was able to serve up *something* on that page it should be able to serve up redirect. Oh well, not really that important. Thanks!

Comment: @Zoredache I tweaked your post slightly and added a note that the second link is dead now. But SSLH is an awesome find!

Comment: It looks like there's another one here: https://github.com/robertklep/node-port-mux

Answer (score 1):

This can be archived by redirecting to a custom "400 - Bad Request" page and modify the redirection with a rewrite rule. In the following example i request

> **http**://test.mydomain.com:**27000**

and get redirected to

> **https**://test.mydomain.com:**27000**

with one virtual host.

Code:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}:27000/$1 [R,L]
```

Or you simply redirect directly to the HTTPS version of the page.

Code:

```
 ErrorDocument 400 https://test.mydomain.com:27000
```

But you will loose the ability to redirect on a real "Bad Request" page.

Comment: Didn't want to vote down on this answer, but this approach doesn't work with Apache 2.4.51

Comment: i have the second code line successfully running for years on a Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Maybe your older version is responding with an other error code? If its 500 you just need to change the line.

Comment: 2.4.51 is the currently latest Apache version

Comment: sry i meant your newer version responds with a different error code. I tested the second code line right now on Apache/2.4.51 (Unix) and it's working perfecly.